# Moving a file to a system-dependent directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch script to automate the movement of a .dll file into a directory.

Unfortunately, the directory won't always be the same and is dependent on the computer being used.

I'm able to find the directory using

```
dir /b /s xxx.exe
```

where xxx is an executable file guarenteed to be in the directory I'm looking for.

Is there any way I can grab the path of that output (minus the xxx.exe) and MOVE the .dll into that directory?

I'm new to batch files, so any tips or best practices are helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s xxx.exe') do (
   echo %%~dpa
   echo move "c:\path\whatever.dll" "%%~dpa"
 )
```

If it looks right, remove the echo from the move line.

Comment: Does 'do' execute the echo command? So I can replace echo with another command to move the file from its current location to the one it finds?

Comment: You probably saw the answer before I edited it to include the move command to use.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your edit afterwards. Thank you very much!